# Mobile Friendly Navigation Bar CSS

Tags: html, css

How do I make a dropdown mobile friendly navigation bar? I have a navigation bar, that display on the left side of the webpage, but I am trying to make a mobile friendly version, that when it is a mobile device, the navigation bar shrinks to the 3 line icon on the top right of the page, and the user has to click on it and then can select the page they want to go to. I already have the "@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){" in my CSS, and I am pretty sure that I have to add the CSS there, but I can not seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Here is an illustration I made of what I have in mind

[image]

HTML

```
<html>

    <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head> 
<nav>

    <a href="#" id="menu-icon"></a>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="default.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="news.asp">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.asp">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.asp">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</html>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: #00008B;
    height: 80%; /* Full height */
    position: fixed; /* Make it stick, even on scroll */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if the sidenav has too much content */
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Change the link color on hover */
li a:hover {
background-color: #808080;
color: white;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){

    ul:active ul { 

        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        padding: 20px;
        background: #fff;
        border: 5px solid #444;
        right: 20px;
        top: 60px;
        width: 50%;
        border-radius: 4px 0 4px 4px;

    }

    li {

        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 10px 0;
        margin: 0;

    } 

    nav:hover ul {

        display: block;

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML and the mentioned CSS `@media only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px){` also

Comment: I wouldn't use max-device-width. I'd just simply use max-width. Works great for me.

Comment: @TyQ, what is the difference?

Comment: @caramba at this point, there are only a few differences, as for the navigation, there is no code in the max-device-width: 1024px section for the navigation bar

Comment: caramba is right, you need to (at least) add both of those things for us to be capable of helping you.

Comment: @JavaSpyder I added the requested code

Comment: Do you have HTML code as well, or are you requesting that we create it for you?

Comment: @JavaSpyder, Sorry about that, I did not realise I forgot the HTML

Comment: Could you describe more precisely what you want to obtain ? The best would be an image illustrating of the expected result.